# Kernel matrix normalisation

Tags: text-mining, kernel-trick

Originally posted in [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/kernel-matrix-normalisation) but never got an answer so reposting here.

Is it ever a *bad* idea to normalise the kernel matrix? By this I mean the method described on page 113 of Shawe-Taylor & Cristianini's "Kernel Methods for Pattern Analysis" (matlab notation):

```
% original kernel matrix stored in variable K
% output uses the same variable K
% D is a diagonal matrix storing the inverse of the norms
D = diag(1./sqrt(diag(K)));
K = D * K * D;
```

I'm specifically thinking of text mining, where the kernel is formed from the $tf-idf$ matrix $T$ (*i.e.* $K = T T'$). The reason I'd like to normalise is that I'm thinking of combining several of such kernels (*e.g.* from bigrams, trigrams etc.) but I'm getting some really weird results when I do.

Summing the kernels without normalisation results in one or the other dominating. (I could use a weighted sum - such as using $1/||K||_F$ where $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm but this seems a bit of a hack - this is unsupervised learning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you understand what you're doing you'll be fine :-)

You're actually normalizing your data to have unit length in feature space. It is equivalent to use this kernel: $K(x,y)/\sqrt{K(x,x)K(y,y)}$. Your data will now fall on a hypersphere of radius 1 in feature space. When you add kernel matrices you're actually "concatenating" feature (not exactly true for all kernels but is is a way to think about it). However in the normalized case the new features will fall on a hypersphere of bounded, known radius.

Could it hurt?

Sure, does the actual value of the feature tell you anything? Consider the case of (normalized) linear kernel [10,10] is a sure 1 and [20,20] is a sure -1 then doing normalization would not be a good idea for your data using this kernel.

[This paper a paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.2658&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about these type of issues.

Comment: nice reference - not seen that one before

Comment: This is interesting.  Is it easy to see that the normalized kernel is a kernel?  And is this related to the normalization that people do in spectral clustering?

Comment: I think it is straight forward. If K(x,y) is a valid dot product (it is \gamma(x)\cdot \gamma(y) in some space), $K(x,y)/\sqrt{K(x,x)K(y,y)}$ is the dot product in the following mapping \theta(x)=\gamma(x)/||\gamma(x)||